# CRM down:Recurring Issue in MSCRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

There is Incident which is occurring periodically in last couple of months(total 3-4 incident till date including today one) by which the CRM is down.

After googling the error logs from the event viewer http://crm2011corner.blogspot.dk/2012/09/crm-key-error-current-key-keytype.html this is what I found.
To resolve such error I have to perform two steps:
Solution Steps:
1.  Started “Microsoft CRM Asynchronous Processing Service" .(start>run type services.msc)
2.  Perform iisreset in cmd prompt

Do we have any idea by which we can fixed this permanently?

Thanks a lot.

Logs:
The current active key (KeyType : CrmWRPCTokenKey) is expired.  This may indicate that a key is not being regenerated correctly.  Current Active Key : CrmKey(Id:7046522a-6b80-e411-b1d5-0050569075fd, ScaleGroupId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, KeyType:CrmWRPCTokenKey, Expired:True, ValidOn:12/10/2014 12:50:50, ExpiresOn:01/12/2015 12:50:50, CreatedOn:12/10/2014 12:50:50, CreatedBy:.  Key Setting : CrmKeySetting(Id:a24534e8-f95d-4885-9b90-91894176bba3, KeyType:CrmWRPCTokenKey, KeyLength:128, KeyGenerationInterval:720, KeyTimeToLive:792, CryptoTimeToLive:72, Algorithm:HMACSHA256, ArchiveLength:1, Enabled:True, ActiveKeys:[ScaleGroupId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000,ActiveKeyId=7046522a-6b80-e411-b1d5-0050569075fd])

Comment: What is the Async service stopping? That is the issue we need to resolve as the key generation issue is a downstream effect. There should be something in the Event Log showing why the Async service stopped.

Comment: there is nothing specific in event log reason by which the service stops but  this makes whole CRM down which afterwords give this logs which I have attach in question

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft Dynamics CRM Asynchronous Processing Service (maintenance)** is responsible for the generation of encryption keys generation for authentication.

Make sure this service is running.

Other tips:

- Check the database for frequently occurring deadlocks. If this is an issue, cleanup and tune your database.
- Check the `asyncoperationbase` table. If it contains, say, 50,000+ records, it should be cleaned up. Ever growing asyncoperation tables are a common source of performance issues and database deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this in CRM 2016 and Dynamics 365 OnPremise environments as well.  I don't have an exact root cause for why this happens as it's not always in organizations with large AsyncOperationBase tables or with slow SQL Servers.  In addition to what Henk answered, below are some steps that can be performed to force generating a new CrmWRPCTokenKey.  Note that while these steps do restart the CRM Asynchronouse Processing Services and IIS, those typically can be done even in mid-day operations without too much interruption for end users since they typically can restart in 30 seconds or less.

> 1. In a command window, run Microsoft.Crm.Tools.WRPCKeyRenewal.exe /R in the CRM Tools folder ( by default).
> 2. Run command prompt as administrator then type iisreset .
> 3. Restart the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Asynchronous Processing Service and Microsoft Dynamics CRM Asynchronous Processing Service
>      (maintenance) services

I'm including an example of what's logged in the CRM Server application event log for more completeness in case someone is searching on the Event ID:.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        MSCRMKeyGenerator
Date:          7/28/2016 10:44:29 AM
Event ID:      18962
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      crm.local
Description:
Current key (KeyType : CrmWRPCTokenKey) is expired.  This can indicate that a key is not being regenerated correctly.  Current Key : CrmKey(Id:58d4835c-393a-e611-9e7a-005056ac0009, ScaleGroupId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, KeyType:CrmWRPCTokenKey, Expired:True, ValidOn:06/24/2016 18:27:53, ExpiresOn:07/27/2016 18:27:53, CreatedOn:06/24/2016 18:27:53, CreatedBy:NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="MSCRMKeyGenerator" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32768">18962</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-07-28T15:44:29.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>251316</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>crm.local</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>CrmWRPCTokenKey</Data>
    <Data>CrmKey(Id:58d4835c-393a-e611-9e7a-005056ac0009, ScaleGroupId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, KeyType:CrmWRPCTokenKey, Expired:True, ValidOn:06/24/2016 18:27:53, ExpiresOn:07/27/2016 18:27:53, CreatedOn:06/24/2016 18:27:53, CreatedBy:NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

If these steps don't resolve the issue, it would be a scenario where you should open a support case with Microsoft CRM/Dynamics 365 support for further troubleshooting and assistance.